# Where are my Windows server Subversion files located?

Tags: svn

I have just set up Subversion on Windows Server 2003 using 
the blog post *http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/01/16/Setting_up_a_Subversion_Server_under_Windows.aspx*
.

I want to see the changes by web access so that any change I commit will directly appear on my website.

Where are those files of the SVN server located?

Comment: What do you mean with 'see the changes by web access'? Could you elaborate?

Comment: The link is broken - it redirects to `dp.g.doubleclick.net`.

Answer (score 0):

The Subversion repository is baked into a relational database stored (according the link you given) in "c:\Documents and Settings\Subversion Repository".

If you want browse the HEAD of your repository with HTTP you need to install Apache with the Subversion module.

Once you have configured it you will able to browse your repository visiting (for example) http://localhost/svn/myproject. See the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for this.

All I had to do was just play with a post-commit script. You dig into the repository folder's hook directory and all you need is there.

I have just updated the server's directory with "svn update" command. And you need to write the script in the post-commit file.

Eventually, any commit will update the server's file, and I can see the change directly from the URL.

On Windows I have created the post-commit.bat file and the following script is placed in it.

```
@ECHO ON

set repo=%1
set rev=%2
set log=C:\subversion\logs\post-commit_log.log
set err=C:\subversion\logs\post-commit_err-log.txt
set svn=svn
set svnpath=C:\subversion\bin
set working=C:\wamp\www\myproject

( echo ========================================================================
echo Start commit %repo% r%rev%
date /t
time /t
) >> %log%

set cmd=%svn% update --username uSeRnAmE  --password StRoNgPaSsWoRd %working%
(start "start-title" /D"%svnpath%" /NORMAL /B %cmd% >> %log%)
```